# Worklight 6.2 iOS binary issue with MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have MFP Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- MyApp runtime (WAR file) is built using MFP 7.1
- My WLAPP's, Adapters and device binaries are built using WL 6.2

Where I need to run 6.2 app inside MFP 7.1 container to mimic my production environment as I can't have two stand alone live server in PROD, one for WL 6.2 and the other for MFP7.1.

My concern is the following for iOS (9+):

The iOS app that is live is built with ATS not configured and bit code disabled using xCode (Version 6.3.1).

What is the configuration on MFP 7.1 that needs to be done to allow the connection from my live application.

WAS security level:

[image]

My IHS which is in front of my MFP server has the SSLCipherSpec as:

[image]

When I compile the xCode project I'm getting :

```
[https://IP:PORT/MobileBanking/apps/services/api/MobileBanking/iphone/query] Host is not responsive.
```

How can I make my 6.2 app works on MFP 7.1.?

Is there a missing configuration I need to add/remove?

I can't make any changes on App level as it is already in PROD. Also I can't migrate the 6.2 app yet as we have timeline/outage issues that we can't meet.

Comment: If the app is not connecting directly to the Worklight server (it's connecting to IHS), then you do not have to worry about the SSL configuration on the Worklight server - only on the IHS server.  In addition to ensuring that TLS 1.2 is enabled, and that at least one of the appropriate cipher suites are enabled, the server certificate (on IHS) must also have a key size of at least 2048 bits (or 256 bit EC key), and signed using SHA-256 or better (i.e., not SHA-1).

Comment: Take a look at this, if you have not seen it already:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/ - if this doesn't help resolve the issue, we'd probably need to log at XCode logs and IHS logs to try to determine why the app is not connecting.

Comment: @patbarron ,Thanks a lot for the info. I will do another round of validation to see why it is not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this blog post: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

7.1 can run wlapp files that were built by 6.2, but those apps (assuming your server is not configured with session independence), but those apps will not benefit of any 7.1 features because you did not re-build them with 7.1 Studio...

Additionally you must have the server configured with TLS 1.2 support and the client application must be configured with TLS. So yes, you must re-build the app even with 6.2 Studio and re-submit to the App Store.

Comment: configuring the client with TLS is by compiling the iOS code with xCode 7+? I believe it will enable it by itself. Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure. Perhaps so. You will need to look at the info.plist file to verify.

Comment: When I build my iOS project using WL6.2, it doesn't add "App Transport Security Settings" to my info.plist. If I try to add it, it gives invalid formate. meaning I can't enable it. Where using MFP7.1 build adds this setting. So my only option is to disable ATS on the MFP server side to make it behave as WL 6.2 to allow the connection from my iOS 6.2 App. I will compare the Ciphers from my WL 6.2 env and see if I can do the same on MFP.

Comment: You cannot disable ATS on the server side. ATS is an iOS "thing" and can be handled only in the plist of the application. if You want to disable ATS see here: http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error -- it sounds more like though that you misconfigured it in your plist than anything else. Note that this is something you need to do in Xcode version that supports ATS.

Comment: You need to add it yourself.

Comment: oK, I will go through the Apple dev and see how I can correctly add it manually

Comment: All the docs indicates that it should be added by default and providing a way to disable it. But I couldn't find how I can add it manually. Would it be possible to provide the config that I need to include in my info.plist to enable ATS manually?

Comment: Look here for an example: https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/